# How to get inner product of Numpy array with different dimension

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two Numpy array with different dimension look like below:

```
arr_a.shape #(2, 10000, 300)
arr_b.shape #(2, 300)
```

I wanted to calculate inner product of above array like this

```
s1 = np.inner(arr_a[0], arr_b[0]) #s1.shape (10000,)
s2 = np.inner(arr_a[1], arr_b[1)  #s2.shape (10000,)
```

Is there any better way to do this in one line rather than to do that twice individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to use [`matmul`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html) / [`@`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.matmul) with an extra dimension:

```
arr_a @ arr_b[..., None]
```

Another would be using [`einsum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html):

```
np.einsum('ijk,ik->ij', arr_a, arr_b)
```

`matmul` broadcasts leading dimensions and multiples out the last two. `einsum` lets you do a sum-product for any matching dimensions.